# Java Spring MongoDB Custom Filter ignore Null Parameters

Tags: spring, mongodb, null

I am trying to filter with a custom Expression and multiple fields.
For the name Field i use a regular expression.
And all the other fields i check if they are contained in a List of Parameters.

```
@Query(value = 
    "{$and:["
        + "{'name': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}},"
        + "{'types': {$in: ?1}},"
        + "{'customer': {$in: ?2}}"
    + "]}")
Optional<List<Object>> findByFilter(
            @Param("name") String name,
            @Param("types") Collection<String> types,
            @Param("customers") Collection<String> customers,
            Pageable pageable);
```

How can i ignore if a Parameter is null?
I tryed the spring expression language but this is not working.

```
@Query(value = 
    "{$and:["
        + "{'name': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}},"
        + "{'types': {$in: ?1}},"
        + "?#{ [2] != null ? {'customer': {$in: [2]}} }"
    + "]}")
Optional<List<Object>> findByFilter(
            @Param("name") String name,
            @Param("types") Collection<String> types,
            @Param("customers") Collection<String> customers,
            Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible, but recommend you use [MongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) which is more *flexible* than `MongoRepository` syntax.

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongotemplate;

Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("name").regex(name).and("types").in(types);
if (customers != null || !customers.isEmpty()) {
    criteria.and("customers").in(customers);
}

List<YourClass> result = mongotemplate.find(Query.query(criteria).with(pageable), YourClass.class);
```